# How to generate tooltip from text file VB2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this txt file with paragraphs in it, each paragraph start with a ^ symbol so that i may identify each line. In my code, i wish to generate a tooltip in a form that displays a random paragraph upon loading.

I have managed to get a string value to the tooltip and it's position, i have managed to "load" the entire text file in another string value, all i have to do now is to find and select a line based on the "^" symbol, remove the symbol and display it in the tooltip. since i plan to edit the txt file in the future so that this becomes an automated process i thought of function to give each line that starts with ^ a number, generate a random number and then display the function. i have made it this far:

```
Public Class Question
Dim quote As String
Dim qn As Double
Private Sub Question_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True

    Dim bquote As String
    bquote = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\texts.txt")

    Dim thesearch As String
    thesearch = "^"

    ' for test quote = "i've made it"
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me, quote)
End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: You could turn `bquote` into an array of quotes using the Split function `Dim quotes() As String = bquote.Split(thesearch.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and then use the random generator to select an array element.

Comment: [**Research**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Split+a+string+VB.NET)

Comment: hello and thank you very much for the reply, i will try this tomorrow and will post what point i've reached

Comment: @VisualVincent i have succeeded today due to your help. if anyone ever needs this again i will post the code below. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that works for this particular problem is:

```
Public Class Question
Dim quote As String
Private Sub Question_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True
    Dim inital_text_load As String
    inital_text_load = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\texts.txt")

    Dim quote_array As String()

    quote_array = inital_text_load.Split("^".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim index As Integer = rand.Next(0, quote_array.Length - 1)

    quote = quote_array(index)

    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me, quote)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: the symbol used in the txt file to sort between lines was ^

Comment: Nice, but this is incorrect: `rand.Next(0, quote_array.Length - 1)`. The _max_ parameter is not inclusive, so you should do: `rand.Next(0, quote_array.Length)` or else it will never pick your last item.

Comment: well now that you placed that in my attention, it's a good thing. as i can now make the final row named ^FIN thank you kind sir